# org.apache.commons.mail attachment file name encoding

Tags: java, apache, encoding, jakarta-mail, attachment

I'm using apache commons mail for sending e-mails with attachments.
My attachment file content is in hebrew and I can see it when I open the file , my problem is when the attachment file name is in hebrew I can't see the name I see ??? instead. (the content I still see o.k).

this is my code:

```
String attachment_file_name = "קובץ מס 1";

HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName(smtp_server);
email.addTo(to_email;
email.setFrom(from_email , "XXXXXXX");
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setCharset("UTF-8");    
email.setHtmlMsg(body);          
email.attach(new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment_file_.toByteArray(), "application/pdf"), 
                                     attachment_file_name , 
                                     "attachment pdf",     
                                     EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);                     

email.send();
```

what do I need to do inorder to see the file name in hebrew (in the correct encoding) ?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have to encode it.

[Javamail, the core library requires this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#whenencode)

Answer (score 0):

[Set the System property "mail.mime.encodeparameters" to "true".](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#encodefilename)

Comment: that will only help you with RFC 2231. The majority of mailers encode with RFC 2047

Comment: And the FAQ entry linked to above tells you what properties to set for that too.